# header php doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, database, header

I made a code in php where a query is made I can not publish database connection data because they are confidential, but the code works fine, the query does work, the problem is that the header does not work only shows me the White screen

```
$buscar = 'DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE idusuario = "'.$_POST['prop'].'"';
$usuariorecord = mysqli_query($landier, $buscar);
$idi=mysqli_insert_id($landier);


$go = "../final.html";
header(sprintf("Location: %s", $go));

?>
```

thank you

Comment: what do you mean by sprintf("Location: %s", $go) ?

Comment: This is just a perfect query to submit an SQL injection to, effortlessly.

Comment: you can be simple here, just say header("Location : ../final.html");

Comment: I already try also with only header("Location: ../final.html"); but still doesn't work :(

Comment: Post your final.html code here

Comment: The file works normal has no extra code only html, and in fact I have this other code in which I call the header but in this if it works
    $query_usuarios = "MyQuery";
    $usuariorecord = mysqli_query($landier, $query_usuarios) ;
    $idi=mysqli_insert_id($landier);

    $go = "../final.html";
    header(sprintf("Location: %s", $go));

Comment: the only diferrence is the query doesn't work is a delete query and in the query that works is an insert query

Answer (score 0):

You have query of remove data then why are you fetching inserted id?

Remove this line from code then try:

```
$idi=mysqli_insert_id($landier);
```

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_insert_id($landier) //returns zero if the last query wasn't an Insert or Update query.....Remove that particular line......

Comment: already removed but doesn't work, xD i solved it writing an echo "all my html script" XD

Comment: where your final.html is located....is it in the same directory or in parent directory...?????